# Detect if you web page is viewed inside a WebView of an app?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a browser base game that for some reason doesn't run when shared on for example LinkedIn because it runs in a webView.

How can you detect if you web page is viewed inside a WebView of an app? I especially need a solution for iOS.

Comment: WebView sends User-Agent with application name and version. Doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not a app developer so I don't know.

Comment: If you're web developer you can verify it by checking User-Agent.)

Comment: It returns "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Pixel XL) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.83 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle that answers this question:

```
var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
        userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
        ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

if( ios ) {

        if ( !standalone && safari ) {

                document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'browser';

        } else if ( standalone && !safari ) {

                document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'standalone';

        } else if ( !standalone && !safari ) {

                document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'uiwebview';

        };

} else {

        document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'not iOS';

};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/6qrbn/