# How to make Messenger open my website in a browser instead of its webview?

Tags: javascript, facebook, webview

My website uses Google OAuth login and my visitors complain that they cannot login.
The reason is that they receive the link in Messenger and FB opens urls in its own webview and not in a browser (Chrome or Safari).

I have figured out how to ask the user to leave the FB window, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54231915/1031191
but I would love to make an automatic mechanism that makes the webpage leave the FB window.

Is there any javascript solution to leave the FB window?